# Why am I getting a "skipping broken view error"?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

This is Drupal 6.x and am having a nightmare of a time to modify a simple drupal form. This is a module file.

function modulename_menu() {
$items = array();
$items['school/registration'] = array(
      'title' => 'Registration Form',
      'page callback'    =>'drupal_get_form',
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );

return $items;
}//end of the function

function modulename_school_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)
{

//  dsm($form_id);

if ($form_id == 'user_registration_form')
   {
// modify the "#submit" form property by prepending another submit handler arra
$form['#submit'] = array_merge(
      array('_modulename_registration_submit' => array()),
      $form['#submit']
    );

}
}

Comment: You are probably being downvoted because of the lack of background information. Are you using the Views module? Does this form have something to do with Views? Are you altering a module or making your own? Tell us what is going on, don't just paste some code.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth a few months afterwards - I just had the same problem. Check out 
http://drupal.org/node/626834#comment-2393090

You probably have an install file with your custom module that doesn't contain all the necessary information.